# How to use CDK fine Grain Assertions Against DefinitionString in AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Following the approach for finely grained assertions, specifically the example against `AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine` in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/testing.html#testing_fine_grained, I can't get the use of `Match.serializedJson()` to work for my own State Machine definition.

Here is a snippet of my generated CloudFormation template -

```
  "StateMachine985JK630": {
   "Type": "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine",
   "Properties": {
    "RoleArn": {
     "Fn::GetAtt": [
      "StateMachineRoleJ4IK852F",
      "Arn"
     ]
    },
    "DefinitionString": {
     "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
       "{\"StartAt\":\"My Task One\",\"States\":{\"My Task One \":{\"Next\":\"My Task Two\",\"Retry\":[{\"ErrorEquals\":[\"Lambda.ServiceException\",\"Lambda.AWSLambdaException\",\"Lambda.SdkClientException\"],\"IntervalSeconds\":2,\"MaxAttempts\":6,\"BackoffRate\":2}],\"Type\":\"Task\",\"ResultPath\":\"$.Auth\",\"ResultSelector\":{\"authString.$\":\"$.Payload\"},\"Resource\":\"arn:",
       {
        "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
       },
       ":states:::lambda:invoke\",\"Parameters\":{\"FunctionName\":\"",
       {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
         "MyTaskOne",
         "Arn"
        ]
       },
       "\",\"Payload.$\":\"$\"}},\"My Task Two\":{\"Next\":\"My Task Three\",\"Retry\"
       ...
      ]
...
```

The test against `DefinitionString` in the example in the documents doesn't handle the Arrays or `Fn::Join` property seen in the above CloudFormation template which is in the rough format of `DefinitionString: { 'Fn::Join': [ '', [Array] ] }`. My below test works as is, however without checking against properties such as `StartAt` it's obviously useless.

My Test -

```
// PASSES
it('should create My Task 1', () => {
      template.hasResourceProperties('AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine', {
        DefinitionString: {
          'Fn::Join': [
            '',
            Match.arrayWith([
              // Match.serializedJson(Match.objectLike({ StartAt: 'My Task One' })), // FAILS
              // Match.serializedJson({ StartAt: 'My Task One' }) // FAILS
              // Match.objectLike(Match.serializedJson({ StartAt: 'My Task One' })) // FAILS
              {
                Ref: 'AWS::Partition',
              },
            ]),
          ],
        },
      });
    });
```

I have tried

- Lifting the example exactly as it is from the docs (and changing expect properties to my own) but fails with

```
Expected JSON as a string but found object at /Properties/DefinitionString
```

which makes sense given the makeup of DefinitionString.

- Adding any of the commented out lines to the `Match.arrayWith([])` fail with

```
Missing element at pattern index 0 at /Properties/DefinitionString/Fn::Join[1] (using arrayWith matcher)
```

but I can't quite make sense of this as the functions I am using are 'like' matches.

- Pasting the entire string `"{\"StartAt\":\"My Task One\"...` directly as it is into the `Match.arrayWith([])` which passes but is far from ideal.

My question is how do I parse the array of strings and objects, then match only what I want? Any guidance would be much appreciated.